# sql server: insert xml attribute="" for date, integer getting error : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: xml, insert

Example code:

```
<root>
<Country_Master ID="30" name="IND" ISO_Code="1" VerNo="3" EmailId="poshendra@gmail.com" Record_Type="N" Inputted_by="" Input_dateTime="10/10/2013"/>
</root>
```

We are generated above XML to insert into SQL tables.

We getting error if `VerNo=""` or `Input_dateTime=""` Conversion failed when converting date/integer  from character string.

Please can you help me to store null if no values passed to attributes.